# How to convert a factor vector to POSIXct in ff or ffbase

Tags: r, posixct, ff, ffbase

After reading in a large data set with `read.csv.ffdf`, one of the columns is time. Such as `2014-10-18 00:01:02`, for 1 million rows in that column. That column is a factor. How do I convert it to `POSIXct` supported by `ff`? Simply using `as.POSIXct()` just turns the values into `NA`

Or when I read in the data set in the beginning, can I specify that column to be `POSIXct`?

My goal is to get the month and days (or even hour). So I'm open to solutions other than converting to `POSIXct`.

For example, we have 9 by 2 table,

```
test <- read.csv.ffdf(file="test.csv", header=T, first.rows=-1)
```

Two columns are ID (numeric class), and time (factor class)

Here is dput

```
structure(list(virtual = structure(list(VirtualVmode = c("integer", 
"integer"), AsIs = c(FALSE, FALSE), VirtualIsMatrix = c(FALSE, 
FALSE), PhysicalIsMatrix = c(FALSE, FALSE), PhysicalElementNo = 1:2, 
    PhysicalFirstCol = c(1L, 1L), PhysicalLastCol = c(1L, 1L)), .Names = c("VirtualVmode", 
"AsIs", "VirtualIsMatrix", "PhysicalIsMatrix", "PhysicalElementNo", 
"PhysicalFirstCol", "PhysicalLastCol"), row.names = c("ID", "time"
), class = "data.frame", Dim = c(9L, 2L), Dimorder = 1:2), physical = structure(list(
    ID = structure(list(), physical = <pointer: 0x000000000821ab20>, virtual = structure(list(), Length = 9L, Symmetric = FALSE), class = c("ff_vector", 
    "ff")), time = structure(list(), physical = <pointer: 0x000000000821abb0>, virtual = structure(list(), Length = 9L, Symmetric = FALSE, Levels = c("10/17/2003 0:01", 
    "12/5/1999 0:02", "2/1/2000 0:01", "3/23/1998 0:01", "3/24/2013 0:00", 
    "5/29/2004 0:00", "5/9/1985 0:01", "6/14/2010 0:01", "6/25/2008 0:02"
    ), ramclass = "factor"), class = c("ff_vector", "ff"))), .Names = c("ID", 
"time")), row.names = NULL), .Names = c("virtual", "physical", 
"row.names"), class = "ffdf")
```

Comment: Please provide a small sample of your data with the output of `dput(head(data))`

Comment: For the factor conversion, you'll need to do an `as.character` on the column first. Then you can pass that into `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: It seems that after applying as.character, the column is still factor class. I think the problem is that ff doesn't support character.... maybe I'm mistaken...

Comment: K forget the `dput` we can't use it because of the pointer.  My fault

Answer (score 1):

You can use with from package ffbase as shown below on a toy example. Best.

```
require(ff)
x <- data.frame(id = 1:100000, timepoint = seq(from = Sys.time(), by = "sec", length.out = 100000))
x$timepoint <- as.factor(x$timepoint)

xff <- as.ffdf(x)
class(xff)
require(ffbase)
xff$time <- with(xff, as.POSIXct(as.character(timepoint)), by = 10000)
ramclass(xff$time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
str(xff[1:10, ])
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ timepoint: Factor w/ 100000 levels "2014-10-20 09:14:10",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ time     : POSIXct, format: "2014-10-20 09:14:10" "2014-10-20 09:14:11" "2014-10-20 09:14:12" "2014-10-20 09:14:13" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `colClasses` when reading in the data.
e.g. with your example of two columns: `ID` (numeric class), and `time` (factor class):

```
test <- read.csv.ffdf(file="test.csv", header=T, first.rows=-1,colClasses = c("integer","POSIXct"))
```